# Inheritance of method access modifiers in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm playing with inheritance to try and fully understand it:

I've created a parent class with a private method and overridden it in the child class and made it public. I have also overriden the toString method differently for each class. Looks like this:

```
public class testparent {
    public String toString(){
        return ("One and two boobaloo");
    }
    private void hitMe(){
        System.out.println("BAM");
    }
}

public class testbaby extends testparent{
    public String toString() {
        return "Bananas";
    }
    public void hitMe(){
        System.out.println("BAMBAM");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        testbaby testy = new testbaby();
        testparent test2 = testy;
        System.out.println(test2);
        //test2.hitMe(); //????? not allowed
        System.out.println(testy);
        testy.hitMe();
    }
}
```

Now, why is it that printing both objects produces "Bananas", but I can't use both classes' hitMe() methods?

Comment: I think that `hitMe` in `testParent` is supposed to be private.

Comment: oops, you're right-- fixed it

Comment: You should follow the java coding convention, which among others say: a class name should start with upper case letter, so you should rename `testbaby` to something like `TestBaby`, and same goes for `testparent`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This because of [*dynamic binding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) of methods and [*static typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) of the language itself.

What happens is that Java is statically typed AND has dynamic binding, so:

- the method `hitMe` can be called only on `testbaby` declared variables because it's private in `testparent` and, because of static typing, Java must ensure that method can be surely called at runtime
- the method `toString` can be called on both objects (since it's even inherited from `Object`) and which one will be effectively called at runtime it's chosen according to the runtime instance and NOT according to the variable declaration (because of dynamic binding)

According to *dynamic binding* methodology, the correct and runtime implementation of a method is chosen at run time according to the real instance of the object, not on the declared one.

This means that, even if you declare `test2` as a `testparent`, it is still a `testbaby` object (since you are assigning to it a `testbaby` instance). At runtime the correct implementation will be the one of the child.

This is perfectly legal though, because a `testbaby` *is* a `testparent`.

Comment: Not in this case.  The call from the testparent type can't be compiled (and wouldn't pass verification if it did compile) because the testparent method is private.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `hitMe` method, I'm talking about both printing "Bananas"

Comment: +1 for terminology: using both *dynamic binding* and *static typing* to explain the 2 issues at hand. You should also link to the wikipedia page explaining those concepts to make the answer even better.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, because when you declare `test2` to be a variable of type `testparent`, you're deliberately throwing away your knowledge that `test2` is "actually" a `testbaby`.

That's part of the point of inheritance -- any code that uses `test2` is only allowed to assume that it's a `testparent` or a subclass of `testparent`, and that code has to work for *all* `testparent` objects, even the ones that aren't `testbaby` objects.

FYI, as far anything outside `testParent` is concerned, the `testParent.hitMe()` method doesn't even exist (with the exception of some evil reflection-based things, which you shouldn't worry about at this stage).  Even `testbaby` doesn't know about the `testParent.hitMe()` method.

Comment: Important key word: *static typing*